# ng-option in angular 1.3 forgets ng-model when the collection is set asyncronously

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing an issue (after upgrading to 1.3 version) with [ng-option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive with ng-model. When the model i set prior to the asynchronously set collection bound to the ng-option and when the model is a decimal value (works fine with integer). No issue in FF, i see issue in IOS safari and chrome atleast.

As you can **[see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvCIpw?p=preview)**:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope , $timeout) {
   $scope.selected = {item: 2.5}; //setting an integer options works just fine example item:2
   //Returns a promise which is resolved with the data/async call simulation
   function getData(){
     return $timeout(function(){
       return [{value:"0",id:0},{value:"0.5",id:0.5},{value:"1",id:1},{value:"1.5",id:1.5},{value:"2",id:2},{value:"2.5",id:2.5},{value:"3",id:3}]
     });
   }

  getData().then(function(data){
      $scope.items = data;  
  });
});
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope , $timeout) {
  $scope.selected = {item: 2.5}; //setting an integer options works just fine example item:2
  
  function getData(){
    return $timeout(function(){
     return [{value:"0",id:0},{value:"0.5",id:0.5},{value:"1",id:1},{value:"1.5",id:1.5},{value:"2",id:2},{value:"2.5",id:2.5},{value:"3",id:3}]
      
    });
  }
  
  getData().then(function(data){
      $scope.items = data;  
  });

  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   {{selected.item}}
   <select ng-model="selected.item" ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in items"></select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Some observations:

- Using `track by item.id` [works fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/8IyP5H?p=preview).
- Setting ng-model only along with setting the collection [works fine too](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8Elmd?p=preview).
- 2 options are getting `selected` attribute on DOM inspection (of the rendered select options) of issue scenario.
- Works fine when id is as string [as well](http://plnkr.co/edit/KqmYge?p=preview).
- If you switch back to angular 1.2.x **[this works just fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTFk4I?p=preview)**

I would like to know why is this happening, or why is it behaving differently when ng-model is 2.5 v/s 2 for example? Am i doing something wrong with any changes in the ng-option usage with 1.3 (Could not find anything in the change log) or in general? Is this a bug?

Any relevant information/help is much appreciated.

Comment: my vote is for this being a bug for the simple reason that it works if `selected` is set when collection for options is set. I also tried in IE10 and original wasn't working there either but works on the version that you set selected at same time as provide collection. Shouldn't matter what order `ng-model` or data for options get set IMO

Comment: I never really got used to using `track-by` simply because it dind't exist in early versions, but maybe that's more critical these days

Comment: track by is little annoying with ng-options (not better than select as) unless someone who really uses form posting and such (where they need actual value being posted).. i believe, with ng-repeat it has its own advantage. And sad part is you cannot use them both together since the functionality is conflicting.

Comment: WIth all the leg work you've done I'd submit this as a bug. No doubt others will run into same issue

Comment: This was sadly not fixed until 1.4.0-beta.0. Commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef

Comment: @tasseKATT My issue is a bit different as you can see that issue is only with specific values...

Comment: @PSL True, but I tried your Plunker and it worked with 1.4.0-beta.0 (unless I tested it wrong), so I assumed your issue got fixed in the large commit I posted, since it involved a lot of refactoring.

Comment: @tasseKATT You may be right... I have not tested using 1.4.0-beta.. But cant use it for my prod though.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed is a bug and has been [logged here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11184) for tracking. The options mentioned in the question itself can resolve this issue temporarily. Also note that 1.4.x does not have this issue.